# Correct approach to multiplication symbol in text

Tags: spacing, symbols, text

I would greatly appreciate advice on the approved approach to providing a multiplication symbol in text. For example:

```
The diameter of the sun is $107 \times$ that of the Earth.
The diameter of the sun is 107 $\times$ that of the Earth.
The diameter of the sun is 107\,$\times$\,that of the Earth.
The diameter of the sun is 107 \texttimes that of the Earth.
The diameter of the sun is 107\,\texttimes\,that of the Earth.
etc.
```

I would love to know your thoughts on which gives the most attractive/readable text spacing, appearance etc.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I would definitely not use a symbol here and use the word times. If you really want the symbol then the second one or the fourth, but corrected to not lose the space so `107 \texttimes\ that` you always need `\ ` after a command name in text But `107 times that` is much better

Comment: “The diameter of the Sun is $107$~times that of the Earth,” No symbol.

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle for your authorative opinion. If you were willing, would you mind crafting it as an answer, so I could accept?

Comment: No disrepect @egreg, I am also very grateful for your thoughts!

Comment: @Bob Notation such as 10× (no space) is used in the context of magnification factors (photography or microscopy). I really wouldn't use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely not use a symbol here and use the word times. If you really want the symbol then the second one or the fourth, but corrected to not lose the space so

```
107 \texttimes\ that
```

you always need `\`after a command name in text But

```
107 times that
```

is much better

Note that you may or may not want to use $107$ to use numbers in text (with the default fonts it will make no difference) if your math fonts digits are visibly distinct from your text ones then you may want to use the text digits (for the same reason that you use times rather than the symbol as this is essentially a sentence). But note that if you need negative numbers in text you can't use -107 (that gives a hyphen) with Unicode tex's you could use U+2212 − but with classic tex fonts it is easier to always use math for numbers, so $107$ and $-107$ as the 8bit TeX fonts don't typically have a minus in the text encodings.